# Camera matrix invalid when aligned with up vector

Tags: c++, camera

I'm currently implementing cameras on my engine and I'm having an issue when the camera is looking from top to the floor (example, eye position 0.,0.,50. and target is 0.,0.,0.) my up vector is 0.,0.,1..

Then when I do the maths, the crossproduct of position and up gives 0.,0.,0. and then the view is screwed and nothing is rendered. If I move the camera, everything works as expected.

How can I solve this?

```
if (node==NULL || target==NULL) return;

node->Update();
eye=node->GetWorldMatrix()*GRPVECTOR(0.0,0.0,0.0); //converts from matrix to vector my vector transformation

target->Update();
obj=target->GetWorldMatrix()*GRPVECTOR(0.0,0.0,0.0);


GRPVECTOR ev;
GRPVECTOR z;
GRPVECTOR x_tmp;
GRPVECTOR x;
GRPVECTOR y;

ev = eye - obj;

ev.Normalize();
z=ev;

x_tmp.CrossProduct(&up,&z);             
if (x_tmp.GetLengthf()==0.0f)
    return;  //my view is screwed, I return 

x_tmp.Normalize();
x=x_tmp;

y.CrossProduct(&z,&x);

this->viewmatrix.matrix[0][0] = x.vector[0];
this->viewmatrix.matrix[0][1] = y.vector[0];
this->viewmatrix.matrix[0][2] = z.vector[0];
this->viewmatrix.matrix[0][3] = 0.0f;

this->viewmatrix.matrix[1][0] = x.vector[1];
this->viewmatrix.matrix[1][1] = y.vector[1];
this->viewmatrix.matrix[1][2] = z.vector[1];
this->viewmatrix.matrix[1][3] = 0.0f;

this->viewmatrix.matrix[2][0] = x.vector[2];
this->viewmatrix.matrix[2][1] = y.vector[2];
this->viewmatrix.matrix[2][2] = z.vector[2];
this->viewmatrix.matrix[2][3] = 0.0f;

this->viewmatrix.matrix[3][0] = -x.vector[0] * eye.vector[0] + -x.vector[1] * eye.vector[1] + -x.vector[2] * eye.vector[2];
this->viewmatrix.matrix[3][1] = -y.vector[0] * eye.vector[0] + -y.vector[1] * eye.vector[1] + -y.vector[2] * eye.vector[2];
this->viewmatrix.matrix[3][2] = -z.vector[0] * eye.vector[0] + -z.vector[1] * eye.vector[1] + -z.vector[2] * eye.vector[2];
this->viewmatrix.matrix[3][3] = 1.0f;

GRPMATRIX Translate;
Translate.BuildTranslationMatrix(-obj.vector[0],-obj.vector[1],-obj.vector[2]); 
this->viewmatrix.GetMulplicationMatrix(&this->viewmatrix,&Translate);
```

Comment: btw, I know why it is screwed, the cross product of 0.0.1 and the normalize of 0.,0.,+50 is 0.,0.,0. . But I dont know how to avoid it, and what to do in such cases. Maybe im doing the camera wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to use the crossproduct for? Your `y` variable means nothing in the sense of view matrices here. Your camera should have definite "direction" (i.e. the direction it is facing) and "right" vectors. You can then take the cross-product of those to derive the camera's "up" vector.

Comment: correct me if im wrong, but I calculate "right" vector using cross product from known Up and Camera (Eye - Target). 

ev = eye - obj;

ev.Normalize();
z=ev;

x_tmp.CrossProduct(&up,&z);

is it correct?